# Dart How to Access File Map Data

Tags: json, dart, directory

So I have successfully stored a map of keys and values onto a json file. I am now trying to read the json file in in order to convert it into objects but am having trouble being able to get those keys and values back.

Json File:

```
{"frc1":"1","frc4":"4","frc5":"5","frc6":"6","frc7":"7","frc8":"8","frc9":"9","frc10":"10","frc11":"11","frc13":"13","frc14":"14","frc15":"15","frc16":"16","frc17":"17","frc18":"18","frc19":"19","frc20":"20","frc21":"21","frc22":"22","frc23":"23","frc24":"24","frc25":"25"}
```

I understand that I need to access the file like below but don't know where to go after.

```
  Future<List<Team>> readTeams(String query) async {
        try {
    final file = await _localFile;
....
}
```

Comment: What is `_localFile`?

Comment: I guess you are looking for https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json